# Spark: Reading Parquet File yields Error in Standalone Mode

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

*Running with SparkContext* = **local**

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext
sc = SparkContext( 'local', 'pyspark')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
path = "/root/users.parquet"
sqlContext.read.parquet(path).printSchema()
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = false)
 |-- favorite_color: string (nullable = true)
 |-- favorite_numbers: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
```

*Running with SparkContext* = **master** [Master with 4 Slaves]

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext
appName = "SparkClusterEvalPOC"
master = "spark://<masterHostName>:7077"
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
path = "/root/users.parquet"
sqlContext.read.parquet(path).printSchema()
```

Output:

```
16/02/01 09:16:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 111.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 111, 10.16.34.110): java.io.IOException: Could not read footer: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file FileStatus{path=file:/root/users.parquet; isDirectory=false; length=615; replication=0; blocksize=0; modification_time=0; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false}
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readAllFootersInParallel(ParquetFileReader.java:247)
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Path is a local path, isn't it?

Comment: yes - running in same host

Comment: Does it mean you run standalone cluster on a single machine? If not is `path` available on all workers?

Comment: Got it. Was assuming master will have file-system shared across with slaves.